# Java libGDX different sizes of animation frames

Tags: java, android, animation, libgdx, 2d-games

How to deal with different sizes of frames? If I setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100) in constructor then some frames are smaller but if I update it then frames are moved to left and up. How to make that every frame will be in the same place?

mayby you can see it
https://i.stack.imgur.com/STKlE.jpg

```
public class Player extends Sprite{

//floats
private float animationTimer;

//box2d variables
public World world;
public Body body;

//enums
public enum State{STANDING, MOVING, SHOOTING, RELOAD, MALEE_ATTACK}
public State currentState;
public State previousState;

//booleans
boolean shoot;
boolean reload;
boolean maleeAttack;

private TextureRegion region;

public PlayScreen playScreen;

public Player(PlayScreen playScreen){
    this.playScreen = playScreen;
    this.world = playScreen.getWorld();
    definePlayer();

    animationTimer = 0;

    region = Assets.instance.playerAssets.idleAniamtion.getKeyFrame(animationTimer);

    setRegion(region);
    setBounds(0, 0, getRegionWidth() / Constants.PPM, getRegionHeight() / Constants.PPM);
    setPosition(0, 0);

    currentState = State.STANDING;
    previousState = State.STANDING;

    shoot = false;
    reload = false;
    maleeAttack = false;
}

public void definePlayer(){
    BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    bodyDef.position.set(100 / Constants.PPM, 100 / Constants.PPM);
    bodyDef.type = BodyDef.BodyType.DynamicBody;
    body = world.createBody(bodyDef);

    FixtureDef fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    CircleShape shape = new CircleShape();
    shape.setRadius(50 / Constants.PPM);
    fixtureDef.shape = shape;
    body.createFixture(fixtureDef).setUserData(this);

    body.setLinearDamping(Constants.LINEAR_DAMPING);
}

public void update(float delta){
    region = Assets.instance.playerAssets.idleAniamtion.getKeyFrame(animationTimer);
    setRegion(getFrame(delta));
    moving();
    //rotate();

}

public void moving(){
    setPosition(body.getPosition().x - getWidth() / 2,  body.getPosition(). y - getHeight() / 2);
//setBounds(0, 0, getRegionWidth() / Constants.PPM, getRegionHeight() / Constants.PPM); update bounds
    if (input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.W) && body.getLinearVelocity().y < 5){
        body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0, 1), body.getWorldCenter(), true);
    }
    if (input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.S) && body.getLinearVelocity().y > -5){
        body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(0, -1), body.getWorldCenter(), true);
    }
    if (input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D) && body.getLinearVelocity().x < 5){
        body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(1, 0), body.getWorldCenter(), true);
    }
    if (input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A) && body.getLinearVelocity().x > -5){
        body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(-1, 0), body.getWorldCenter(), true);
    }
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.R)){
        reload = true;
    }

    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.F)){
        maleeAttack = true;
    }
    if (Gdx.input.isButtonPressed(Input.Buttons.LEFT)){
        shoot = true;
    }

}

public TextureRegion getFrame(float delta){
    TextureRegion region;

    currentState = getState();

    switch (currentState){
        case MOVING:
            region = Assets.instance.playerAssets.moveAnimation.getKeyFrame(animationTimer);
            break;
        case SHOOTING:
            maleeAttack = false;
            region = Assets.instance.playerAssets.shootAniamtion.getKeyFrame(animationTimer);
            if (Assets.instance.playerAssets.shootAniamtion.isAnimationFinished(animationTimer)){
                shoot = false;
            }
            break;
        case RELOAD:
            region = Assets.instance.playerAssets.reloadAnimation.getKeyFrame(animationTimer);
            if (Assets.instance.playerAssets.reloadAnimation.isAnimationFinished(animationTimer)){
                reload = false;
            }
            break;
        case MALEE_ATTACK:
            region = Assets.instance.playerAssets.maleeAttackAnimation.getKeyFrame(animationTimer);
            if (Assets.instance.playerAssets.maleeAttackAnimation.isAnimationFinished(animationTimer)) {
                maleeAttack = false;
            }
            break;
        default:
            region = Assets.instance.playerAssets.idleAniamtion.getKeyFrame(animationTimer);
            break;
    }

    animationTimer = currentState == previousState ? animationTimer + delta : 0;
    previousState = currentState;

    return region;
}

public State getState(){
    if ((body.getLinearVelocity().x > 1 || body.getLinearVelocity().x < -1 || body.getLinearVelocity().y > 1 || body.getLinearVelocity().y < - 1)  && !reload && !shoot && !maleeAttack){
        return State.MOVING;
    }
    if (shoot && !reload){
        return State.SHOOTING;
    }
    if (reload && !maleeAttack){
        return State.RELOAD;
    }
    if (maleeAttack){
        return State.MALEE_ATTACK;
    }
    else {
        return State.STANDING;
    }
}

public Vector2 getMousePosition(){
    Vector2 mousePosition;
    mousePosition = playScreen.getViewport().unproject(new Vector2(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY()));
    return mousePosition;
}

public float getMouseAngle(){
    float angle = (float) Math.atan2(getMousePosition().y - body.getPosition().y, getMousePosition().x -  body.getPosition().x);
    return angle;
}

public void rotate(){
    setOrigin(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2 );
    setRotation((float) (getMouseAngle() * (180/Math.PI)));
    body.setTransform(body.getPosition(), getMouseAngle());
}
```

}

Comment: Are you using viewport or virtual screen?

Comment: yes, i'm using ExtendViewport.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the additional data information a TextureAtlas provides as an AtlasRegion.

1. One complete animation should have the same (width/height) size for each keyframe. Pick a size where the biggest keyfarme fits into. Also be aware of positioning correctly. Have the same pivot point for each keyframe.
2. To avoid wasting space when packing your TextureAtlas enable "trim" function. Should be supported by any TexturePacker Tool out there.
3. The texture data file (for libGDX) then has entries like this:

> ```
> walk_animation
>   rotate: false
>   xy: 794, 235
>   size: 86, 109
>   orig: 160, 170
>   offset: 37, 22
>   index: 5
> ```

4. Use the AtlasRegion to draw things at the correct size and position:

> ```
> float width = 400; // pick your size here
> float height = 300;
>
> float offsetPctX = atlasRegion.offsetX / atlasRegion.originalWidth;
> float offsetPctY = atlasRegion.offsetY / atlasRegion.originalHeight;
>
> float scaleWidth = (float) atlasRegion.packedWidth / atlasRegion.originalWidth;
> float scaleHeight = (float) atlasRegion.packedHeight / atlasRegion.originalHeight;
>
> float drawWidth = width * scaleWidth;
> float drawHeight = height * scaleHeight;
>
> float regionOffsetX = offsetPctX * width;
> float regionOffsetY = offsetPctY * height;
>
> float drawScaleX = 1; // adjust to your needs
> float drawScaleY = 1;
>
>
> float drawOriginX = 0; // adjust to tour needs
> float drawOriginY = 0;
>
> float drawRotation = false;
>
> float x = 100 + offsetX + regionOffsetX; // adjust to your needs
> float y = 100 + offsetY + regionOffsetY;
>
> spriteBatch.draw(atlasRegion, x, y, drawOriginX, drawOriginY, drawWidth, drawHeight, drawScaleX, drawScaleY, drawRotation);
> ```

Comment: what is rc., I have error with this. Can I use this if i have two animations but different size? One is bigger and "jump" little bit to top left corrner.

Comment: I removed the rc. part. offsetX/Y is just an offset number you set for your sprite. Leave it to 0 when not used. This is the code of one of my projects which has animations where animation frames sometimes have different sizes.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the resizing of the texture just create a variable size used to set the bounds. The bound needs to set every frame.

```
public class Player extends Sprite {

    private Body body;
    private Vector2 size;

    public Player(){

        this.size = new Vector2( getRegionWidth() / Constants.PPM, getRegionHeight() / Constants.PPM );
    }

    public void update( float delta ){

        Vector2 position = body.getPosition();

        setRegion( getFrame( delta ) );
        setRotation( MathUtils.radDeg * body.getAngle() );
        setBounds( position.x, position.y, size.x, size.y );
        setOriginCenter();
    }

    public void rotate(){

        this.body.setTransform( body.getPosition(), getMouseAngle() );
    }
}
```

Comment: If i set bound every frame then frames are "jumping" (setbouds(posistion.x, position.y, getWidth, getHeight)) and if i do like you then frames are still resizing because bounds are still the same size.

Comment: I tried using sprite class before but somehow it doesnt render properly. It creates a lot of overhead that you dont really need. Just use the batch.draw() instead its so much easier to debug than sprite.draw().